# In the double list is cast to a set,Why does the result output an empty set?

Tags: python, list, set, double, union

As shown, in Python, each list element in the double list is cast to a set, and then the Union method is called. Why does the result output an empty set?
[This is my code in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhfNa.png)

Comment: The union of two sets is the elements that appear in _both_ sets. Since `b` is an empty set then it's union with any other set will also be an empty set. You are probably looking for `update` which can also be written as `b |= a`.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you reset the variable `b` during each iteration of the loop, it will result in a non-empty set:

```
a = [[2,2],[3,1]]
b = set()
for i in a:
    b = b.union(set(i))
print(b)
```

Output:

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

Does this help?